# Получить исходный адрес сокращенной ссылки

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-2.x

Часто интернет ссылки сокращают для удобства через сторонние сервисы. Можно ли как-то проследить конечный адрес через `selenium` на Питоне?

Comment: `selenium` - интерфейс с браузером, пока не идти по короткой ссылке "в интернет", в браузере дополнительной инфы нет, ну а "в интернет" проще через  `requests`, как в приведенном ответе.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30156125/5741205):

```
import requests

def unshorten_url(url):
    return requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True).url
```

проверка:

```
url = 'https://goo(.)gl/beQxCE'

In [31]: unshorten_url(url)
Out[31]: 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847061/python-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%
D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8'
```